# Select state on first pagination

Tags: jquery, pagination, carousel

I'm trying to make a carousel display a select state on the first displayed slide in a carousel.

**JSFiddle** 
[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Z8QNW/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div id='mySwipe' style='max-width:500px;margin:0 auto' class='swipe'>
  <div class='swipe-wrap'>
    <div><b>0</b></div>
    <div><b>1</b></div>
    <div><b>2</b></div>
    <div><b>3</b></div>
    <div><b>4</b></div>
    <div><b>5</b></div>
  </div>
</div>

<nav>
    <ul id="nav">
    <li>0</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<div style='text-align:center;padding-top:20px;'>
  
  <button id ="mySwipePrev">prev</button> 
  <button id ="mySwipeNext">next</button>

</div>
```

Comment: So what's the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `selected` class to first `li` element using:

```
$("#nav li").eq(0).addClass("selected");
```

And then I modified code in `callback` function to select based on `index` instead of `index-1`:

```
$Elements.eq(index).addClass("selected");
```

And then I modified code in case of `prev` and `next` button click events to select based on `mySwipe.getPos()` instead of `mySwipe.getPos()-1`:

```
$('#mySwipePrev').on('click', function () {
       mySwipe.prev();
       $navLi.removeClass('selected');
       $navLi.eq(mySwipe.getPos()).addClass('selected');
   });
   $('#mySwipeNext').on('click', function () {
       mySwipe.next();
       $navLi.removeClass('selected');
       $navLi.eq(mySwipe.getPos()).addClass('selected');
   });
```

and on click of navigation li elements (0,1,2,3,4..), use `$(this).index()` instead of `$(this).index()+1`(which will add +1 to index)

```
$navLi.on ('click', function () {
        window.mySwipe.slide($(this).index(), 200);
        
        $(this).siblings().removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    });
```

<kbd>**[DEMO FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Z8QNW/4/)**</kbd>

Comment: Clicking '0' in the pagination actually takes it back to slide 1 though